# Removing Status Bar In IOS 8 When Using A UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

I am trying to remove the status bar from my app when moving between views in a UINavigationController.

I have a UINavigationController that has the status bar removed. I then select an image using UIImagePickerController, I think it is this that is resetting the status bar appearance.

After selecting the UIImage I push another view and present the image, the problem is that the status bar has reappeared.

I have tried a number of approaches including calling **prefersstatusbarhidden** on both views without without any luck.

Any ideas how to remove the status bar?

Thanks

Comment: Try this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. I thought that was used for IOS 6. If you put it in an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding the status bar manually using this 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`

Comment: using Xcode 6.0 for iOS 8, its not working. I just put this code in the Did load of my root View Controller

Comment: Its working for me, could it be because I am using it in a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1):

If using iOS8, add

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

to your view controller. You will need to add this to each view controller as required.

You could alternatively specify a value for the key `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info.plist to specify your status bar preferences app-wide.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a case in your application where you have controllers in the navigation controller. I found myself having to subclass UINavigationController, override prefersStatusBarHidden, and return nil. Which will also probably ensure that the status bar is hidden consistently in all VCs, if that's what you want.